# How can I crack the password using a session id?

Tags: javascript, html, session, session-cookies

I have session ids. I can bypass login pages using session ids. 
How can I crack the password using a session id?

Comment: Unless the programmer was stupid and put the password in the session, you can't. There's no reason to do that. The session just needs to contain the username.

Comment: can you change the password without entering it?

Comment: @dandavis no. if you are using jsession for bypassing login page. so you can't change the password.